# How to access associative arrays in Python

Tags: python, associative-array

How to print the values in the `0` key line by line, then values in `1` key subsequently? How do we access this whole values of associative array?

```
glyph = {
    '0': [" ##### ", " ## ## ", "## ## ", "## ## ", "## ## ", " ## ## ", " ##### "], 
    '1': [" ## ", " #### ", " ## ", " ## ", " ## ", " ## ", " ###### "]
}
```

Comment: `glyph['0']` will get you the values associated with the '0' key. Similarly, `glyph['1']` will get you the values associated with the '1' key. In Python, these are called dictionaries, not associated arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
for valuelist in glyph.values():
    for value in valuelist:
        print(value)


 ##### 
 ## ## 
## ## 
## ## 
## ## 
 ## ## 
 ##### 
 ## 
 #### 
 ## 
 ## 
 ## 
 ## 
 ######
```

To access an individual list use `glyph['0']`, `glyph['1']`, etc.

To get a list of all of the values, use `list(glyph.values())`.

To make them into one large list, use a list comprehension:

`[i for j in glyph.values() for i in j]`.

Note that dictionaries are not sorted, so you may want to do something like this:

```
for valuelist in {key: glyph[key] for key in sorted(glyph)}:
    for value in valuelist:
        print(value)
```

Where `{key: glyph[key] for key in sorted(glyph)}` creates an inline dictionary based on a `sorted` version of `glyph`.

Or look into `collections.OrderedDict` if you want it to be ordered.
For further reference, look up “dictionaries in python”.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a `SortedDict` or other non-`dict` mapping structure, there is no guarantee that you will iterate in sorted order of the keys. If you care about getting the `'0'` values, then the `'1'` values, etc., you need something like this:

```
[x for x in glyph[y] for y in sorted(glyph.keys())]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[y for y in [x  for x in glyph.values()]]
```

List Comprehension Way.

Comment: You can use double iteration directly without creating an inner list.

Comment: This is just the same as `list(glyph.values())` -- no need for a list comprehension.